How to implement 2FA with MS Authenticator mobile and KeyPass desktop app for robot python selenium framework
Scenario : I have to configure KeyPass 2 application to read the code from MS Authenticator(KeyPass app is configured with MS Authenticator mobile app) via token and pass the code on login screen(2FA screen where we enter the code) and click on Verify to successfully login.
Below is the code written in python via pyotp framework and for some reason it does not works.
otpKeypass.py file
import pyotp
import time

secretkey = 'abcdefxyz123456'
login = 'test.topt@testapp.com'
issueapp = 'Secure App'

totp = pyotp.TOTP(secretkey).provisioning_uri(name=login, issuer_name=issueapp)

Below is the robot-selenium framework steps for login functionality
LoginToApp.robot file
*** Settings ***
*** Variables ***
${login_textbox}        xpath://sample
${password_textbox}     xpath://sample
${code_textbox}         xpath://sample
${verify_button}        xpath://sample

*** Keywords ***
Enter UserId Password MSAuthCode and click Verify
    [arguments] ${userid}   ${password} ${msauthcode}
    Set Selenium Speed  1 seconds
    Input Text      ${login_textbox}    ${userid}
    Input Password      ${password_textbox} ${password}
    Input MSAuthCode    ${code_textbox}     ${msauthcode}
    Click Button        ${verify_button}


Utility.robot file
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary
Resource    LoginToApp.robot

*** Variables ***
${url}              xpath://sample
${browser_name}         xpath://sample
${userid}           xpath://sample
${password}         xpath://sample
${msauthcode}           

*** Keywords ***
Open the web browser with the application url
    Open Browser        ${url}      ${browser_name}
    Run keyword and Ignore Error        Acccept Cookies
    Title Should Be     ${title}        ***issue is here i guess***
    maximise browser window

